# Existance of inverse operators for Hermitian adjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I have one assumption that I can't prove. Maybe there are some other conditions which I didn't take into account.

> My assumption: 
>   Suppose $a$ and $a^\dagger$ is Hermitian adjoint operators and $[a,a^\dagger]=1$. I want to prove that there are no inverse operators for $a$ and $a^\dagger$.

I'm looking forward to any help.

Comment: What is $[.,.]$?

Comment: The commutator of two operators, $[A,B] = AB-BA$.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60994/2451